# jQuery input change doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make something like a shopping cart, but just with an order form.
I am using [this pattern](https://codepen.io/BraadMartin/pen/qENGdZ?editors=1111) to fire input changes, but it doesn't work in my case.

Here what I have first.

```
<div class="ingrid__table-row">
   <div class="ingrid__table-data ingrid__table-item">Lemon</div>
   <div class="ingrid__table-data ingrid__table-weight">15g</div>
   <div class="ingrid__table-data ingrid__table-price">10</div>
</div>
```

With jQuery, on click, I take the data from `ingrid__table-data` and add to the suitable input into `.order__container`.

Then, on the same click, a number input is appended, which will enable to choose the quantity of the selected products.

```
$('.order__container').append(`<input class="bul-order-info__input bul-order-info__qnt" type="number" name="Quantity" min="1" value="1">`)
```

And it appears on a webpage in the order form.

I need to detect the value changes of **"number type input"** and fire other events.
But the input changes are not detected, although if I create the same input element manually in HTML document, these changes are detected perfectly as it's shown [here](https://codepen.io/BraadMartin/pen/qENGdZ?editors=1111)

How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: You need to bind the change event to the new number type input once it is created (which is after the append statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess based on the info you provided is that you are trying to attach the on change event to the dynamically created inputs on this way:

```
$('.bul-order-info__input').change( function () {...} );
```

But with the code before you are aren't applying those changes to any input because none of them exists when you are creating the event handlers, so you have to bind the events to an existing element like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.bul-order-info__input', function() {...});
```

The element doesn't have to be always document, but I tend to use it, because is the only one that always will be present. However, something like this is also valid:

```
$('.order__container').on('change', '.bul-order-info__input', function() {...});
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. But now with this code, other elements have the same problem, so I can't manipulate them. Like here, I want to change ' .bul-order-info__price' value, but it's not detected. How can I make other appended elements visible for jQuery? `$(document).on('change', '.bul-order-info__qnt', function(){` `$('.bul-order__container .bul-order-info__price').val() == 5;` `console.log('on change fired'); });`